# Angular JS : how i can change content using Json data

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I receive a json object via an api rest. I want to change the content of my page when the number of places recieved from json = 0.
i have this JSON format :

```
{
date:"2016-06-30T01:01:01"
id:5
places:[]
}

{
date:"2016-06-30T01:01:01"
id:5
places:
{place: 57}

{
 date:"2016-06-30T01:01:01"
id:5
places:
{place: 57}

{place: 58}

{place: 59}

{place: 60}
}
```

my controller Angular :

```
$scope.LoadAllSpots = function () {

        SpotConfigurationService.GetListSpots(function (datas) {
            $scope.CAMs = datas;
            console.log(datas);
            angular.forEach($scope.CAMs, function (value, Key) {
                if (value.places.lenght == 0) {
                    $scope.ActiveAjoutPlace = false;

                }

            });
        }
```

my html page :

if place recievied from json = 0 i display  the first row  else i display the other:  have you an idea please

```
 <div class="row " ng-show="ActiveAjoutPlace">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-if="@ViewBag.IsLeft">

          <div class="ImgCamera col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">

         </div>  
       </div>
</div> 

  <div class="container">

<div class="row " ng-show="!ActiveAjoutPlace">

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ListPlace ">

         <div class="PlaceNumber">

          <div class="input-group input-group-left SelectStyle">

                  <select class="form-control">

      <option>place 124</option>

                </select>

             </div>

        </div>

       <div class="row RowPicto">

             <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

               <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Resources/Common/pic_handicap.svg ")" />

         </div>
                <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

            <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Resources/Common/pic_Elec_car.svg ")" />

            </div>
                <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">

                  <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Resources/Common/pic_moto.svg ")" />

            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row RowPicto">

             <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">

                  <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Resources/Common/car.svg ")" />


             </div>

          <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">

               <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Resources/Common/pic_famille.svg ")" />

            </div>
                <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">

              <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Resources/Common/pic_GPL_car.svg ")" />

         </div>

        </div>

         <br/>

         <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ">

          <button value="ToggleContent"click="toggleContent()">Supprimer</button>

           </div>

         </div>       
     </div>         
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-if="!@ViewBag.IsLeft">       
         <div class="ImgCamera col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">        
        </div>      
      </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Actually your json having lots of places have more than 0 value and one =0 value. so how you re planning the display.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not json because in json format name property and property should be string.

And it should contain `,` after `}`

So if I understand correctly you display some data gathered from rest API call and you assign it to `$scope.CAMs` and if I understand you want to display two different divs if `$scope.CAMs` is empty or not, right?

You can just use `ng-if` directive like so:

```
<div ng-if="CAMs.length > 0"> There is data </div>
<div ng-if="CAMs.length == 0"> CAMs is empty </div>
```

However `$scope.CAMs` need to be valid object or JSON.

---

Same with children:

```
<div ng-if="CAMs.places.length > 0"> There is data </div>
<div ng-if="CAMs.places.length == 0"> CAMs is empty </div>
```

Comment: yes i have a valid json  :)  my probleme is how i can change content when i recieved data from json

Comment: i have this page modified can you say him

Comment: i need to change content if CAMs.places  ==0 and cams.places != 0 the data is recieved from json

Comment: Just use CAMs.places.length